# How to draw lines between 2 or more points ? (Points can be changed dynamically)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

I am very new to d3.js need some help. I am trying to draw a line between 2 points. My problem here is everything should be dynamic, i.e. we usually follow a rule of telling `x1`, `x2`, `y1` and `y3` positions. Here's an example

```
var canvas = d3.select("body")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", 500)
                    .attr("height", 500);

var line = canvas.append("line")
                 .attr("x1", 0) // x1 position
                 .attr("y1", 100) // y1 position
                 .attr("x2", 400) // x2 position
                 .attr("y2", 400) // y2 position
                 .attr("stroke", "green")
                 .attr("stroke-width", 10);
```

I want those positions to be created dynamically, i.e. when I click on the webpage a point should be created and drag it from the position and place it in some other position. How can I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
A line is a simple line between two points and is described by four required attributes.

    x1: The x position of the first end of the line as measured from the left of the screen.
    y1: The y position of the first end of the line as measured from the top of the screen.
    x2: The x position of the second end of the line as measured from the left of the screen.
    y2: The y position of the second end of the line as measured from the top of the screen.

The following is an example of the code section required to draw a line;

holder.append("line")          // attach a line
    .style("stroke", "black")  // colour the line
    .attr("x1", 100)     // x position of the first end of the line
    .attr("y1", 50)      // y position of the first end of the line
    .attr("x2", 300)     // x position of the second end of the line
    .attr("y2", 150);    // y position of the second end of the line

This will produce a line as follows;

enter image description here

The line extends from the point 100,50 to 300,150 (x1,y1 to x2,y2).
```

For more details [refer](https://leanpub.com/D3-Tips-and-Tricks/read#leanpub-auto-line)

Comment: Mr shajeer thanks for your reply , the problem here is x1,x2,y1 and y2 which are position of points are dynamic , whenever i click on any point in my webpage the position of x1 and y1 will be known

Answer (score 0):

So first you will need to append your line to the svg just as you are doing
Snippet below:

```
var mySVG = d3.select("body")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", 500)
                    .attr("height", 500);

var line = mySVG.append("line")
                 .attr("class", ".line")//note: added a class to select later for dynamically updating.
                 .attr("x1", 0) // x1 position
                 .attr("y1", 100) // y1 position
                 .attr("x2", 400) // x2 position
                 .attr("y2", 400) // y2 position
                 .attr("stroke", "green")
                 .attr("stroke-width", 10);
```

In your drag end callback you can **update** the line using ***select*** as below.

```
mySVG.select(".line")
                 .attr("x1", 200) // x1 new position
                 .attr("y1", 300) // y1 new position
                 .attr("x2", 400) // x2 new position
                 .attr("y2", 400) // y2 new position
                 .attr("stroke", "green")
                 .attr("stroke-width", 10);
```

hope this helps!

Comment: `.attr("x1", 0) // x1 position
                 .attr("y1", 100) // y1 position
                 .attr("x2", 400) // x2 position
                 .attr("y2", 400)`

Comment: `.attr("x1", 0) ` , here we are passing the position as 0 , i want to avoid this , "x - axis" and "y - axis", should be told to point when there is a mouse button click event , x and y axis value also changes whenever user is dragging and dropping the point to some other position , giving an example if x = 0 and y = 50 when mouse was clicked , same point is dragged to some other position i.e., x = 10 and y = 60 should happen

Comment: Ok, so you must be having the drag and drop callback on both the start/end points.
When the drag ends i.e. in the callback you need to fire the **update** snippet with the new X and Y.

Comment: how to record X and Y position ?